# Compute e using Euler's expansion

Tags: programming-challenge, mathematics, scheme, sicp

Given the following task:

> Exercise 1.38.  In 1737, the Swiss
>   mathematician Leonhard Euler published
>   a memoir De Fractionibus Continuis,
>   which included a continued fraction
>   expansion for e - 2, where e is the
>   base of the natural logarithms. In
>   this fraction, the Ni are all 1, and
>   the Di are successively 1, 2, 1, 1, 4,
>   1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 8, .... Write a program
>   that uses your cont-frac procedure
>   from exercise 1.37 to approximate e,
>   based on Euler's expansion.

I wrote this solution:

```
(define (i-cont-frac n d k)
  (define (iterate result i)
    (define (next n) (- n 1))
    (if (= i 0) result
        (iterate (/ (n i) 
                    (+ (d i)           
                    result)) (next i))))
  (iterate 0 k))

(define (divisible? a b) (= (remainder a b) 0))
(define (compute-e k)
  (define (n i) 1)
  (define (d i) (cond ((= i 1) 1)
                      ((= i 2) 2)
                      ((divisible? (- i 1) 3) 
                       (* (/ (- i 1) 3.0) 2.0))
                      (else 1.0)))
  (+ 2 (cont-frac n d k)))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `d` is not quite right.  It produces incorrect results for some values of `i` and it has two special cases which are not necessary.  A possible definition is:

```
  (define (d i)
    (cond
      ((divisible? (+ i 1) 3) 
       (* (/ (+ i 1) 3) 2))
      (else 1)))
```

This is because i is 1-indexed (series begins with i = 1).  If you want a decimal instead of a fraction as your result, change the multiplier to 2.0 and the else value to 1.0.

Another way to write `d` is:

```
  (define (d i)
    (let
        ((d-value (* (/ (+ i 1) 3) 2)))
      (if (integer? d-value) d-value 1)))
```